# Using a recordset without blocking resources

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic, ado, recordset

I am dealing with some performance issues on an older codebase here.
The issues appear in the Sql Server. Either the queries time out or  `The request limit for the database is 2000 and has been reached`. This error message occurs earlier than I think it should when doing load testing.

The code is executing vbscript database queries by using this code

```
  Dim cmd, i, rsx
  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  cmd.CommandText = querytext
  ' 1 -> adCmdText
  cmd.CommandType = 1
  For i = 0 To UBound(parameters)
    cmd.Parameters.Append(create_variant_input_parameter(cmd, "", parameters(i)))    
  Next
  Set cmd.ActiveConnection = connection 
  Set rsx = cmd.Execute()
```

and then using it like this

```
do while not rsx.eof
    Test = Test & rsx("Test") & ","
rs.movenext : loop
rs.close : set rs = nothing
```

I read that the recordset object maintains a connection to the server, is this blocking database workers unnecessarily while looping through the recordset? These loops are also nested a lot of times, so this here is a very simple example.

If yes, how could I just save the result in a recordset that does not maintain the connection without having to rewrite the entire codebase?

Comment: Tell us about `connection`. How is that created and managed?

Comment: Once at the beginning of the request and then reused for each of the queries

Comment: Within the same request, that should be okay, as long as you're SURE it's scoped to just that request. Newer ADO.Net often even wants a completely new connection for _ever single query_, and there are important reasons for this related to the connection limit you're running into. How are you closing the connection at the end of the request?

Comment: By request I mean the whole page load. And we are closing it by just saying conn.close at the end of the page

Comment: Are you sure that code executes? Anything that might call response.redirect, server.transfer, response.end, etc before reaching that code?

Comment: I'd have to check page by page, most of the time it should execute but I am sure the is places where it was forgotten

Comment: Every time it's missed, a connection can hang open until a timeout, which could be several minutes to... _much_ longer if it's configured that way. If it happens often enough you get this exact error. The error could come up on _any_ query, but you'll tend to see it on the query or queries that are executed most often or first in the page.

Comment: I only get errors on high load though, what you described would also happen on low loads

Comment: Not necessarily. The lost connections do eventually time out, and under low loads this can happen fast enough to avoid errors. It's only when the load reaches the point that new connections are orphaned at a rate where you reach the limit before they can be cleaned up.

Comment: Okay, I can search for redirects and check if they all close correctly. So you are saying keeping the recordset open while doing server side code is not a big deal?

Comment: It's fine, as long as you close it as soon as you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a "firehose cursor" with ADODB.Recordset.

Here's how to build one in VBA:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
End With
```

These are server-side, forward-only, read-only cursors that push data directly from the server to the client recordset that you can then loop. Fetch the data and then be sure to close the recordset to free the resources on the server.

It's worth noting that you can also play with the recordset's `CacheSize` to modify performance.

You can adapt this example to your VBScript requirement.